# wordpress posts to auto expire

Tags: wordpress, function

I wanted my wordpress posts to auto expire after 15 days (turn into drafts), but also to protect posts in some categories. I was reading some topics about this and added following code to my theme functions, but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong here? Please help!

```
function expire_posts() {
global $wpdb;
$daystogo = "15";
$protcats = array( 9,10 );
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_status` = 'draft' WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND `post_category` != '$protcats' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > '$daystogo')";
$wpdb->query($sql);
}

add_action('wp_head', 'expire_posts');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [post expirator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/) plugin to do this job. You just have to configure it as your requirements. The installation process and other details are provided with the plugin. And its surely have congiguration option.

Comment: Yeah, i know about this one, but it doesn't offer option for categories. I guess that problem with my code is recognizing categories too because there is no column "post_category" in wp_post database and i just don't know how to retrieve it, or where is it assigned :s

Answer (score 1):

You are putting an array ($protcats) in a string.
Try `echo $sql;` and you will see it doesn't put your cat ID's in the query but `array`.
Try this:

```
$protcats = array( 9,10 );

$excludeCats = '';
foreach($protcats as $cat){
    $excludeCats .= " AND `post_category` != '$cat' "; //add each category to it's own exclude
}
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_status` = 'draft' WHERE `post_type` = 'post' ". $excludeCats ." AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > '$daystogo')";
```

Comment: Thanks janw it's looking good as you coded. But it doesn't work :s because there is no post_category column in wp_post database any more, i have to find how to pull that data, but i can't find it yet :s BTW even if i try without adding categories it doesn't work, i'm obviously doing something wrong...

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't check the query itself, I'll come back later with the awnser

Comment: Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query not sure if it will work. But it's easy to select categories, of exclude